# What event is raised when the Start button is pressed in Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, lifecycle

I used MediaCapture APIs in my App. Let's say I started recording and preview. During recording, I pressed Start key and quickly come back to the App by long pressing Back key and selecting my app (task swap). The result is that the preview is frozen either running on Emulator or 8.1 WP hardware. I don't find a better event to register for Start key. I understand that this.Resume can handle restoration when your APP is being deactivated. But here I mean I switch back from Start within 2~3 seconds and the Resume call is not get called. I am thinking that I can disable preview when Start key is pressed as a workaround. Then when App is brought back to foreground, user can restart recording. However, both scenarios I can't find a proper event. Of course if preview is not frozen when APP is swapped back, I don't need to do anything. Now it seems preview is not working after task swapped back from Start.

Here are the APIs I am using

```
_mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(_profile, _recordStorageFile);

capturePreview.Source = App._mediaCapture;

_mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're hitting here has to do with the fact that as long as the debugger is attached, suspending/resuming won't work like it will once your app is running on its own.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974425.aspx

Try the same thing you're doing right now, except press the Suspend button in VS once your app is in the background. To bring it back, press the Resume button. Alternatively, try the same thing without the debugger attached.
As long as you're handling the Suspending/Resuming events correctly, MediaCapture lifecycle won't be a problem.

To learn more, have a look at the UniversalCameraSample on the Microsoft github repository: http://aka.ms/2015builduniversalcamerasample. It targets Windows 10, but a lot still applies to 8.1.

Comment: I unplugged USB cable and it still behaves the same. I have code handing Suspend event and Back key. Those are not called when I pressed Home key.

Comment: What I meant was that you should launch your app from the app list, not from Visual Studio. Then press start, and navigate to a different app. After about 5 seconds or so, your Suspending event will execute. When you come back, the Resuming event will trigger (or the Launched/Activated event, depending on whether you were shutdown or left in suspension, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx). Maybe you should edit your original question to show your event handler code for the Suspending and Resuming events.

Answer (score 1):

There are three events you can register for.

- [`CoreWindow.Activated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.activated.aspx) will be raised when you are no longer the foreground app. This can happen because the user switched away, or because something like a Reminder or Phone Call popped up on top, etc. Simply getting a toast notification does **not** raise the Activated event.
- [`CoreWindow.VisibilityChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.visibilitychanged.aspx) will be raised when you are no longer visible. This happens when the user switches away, locks the phone, etc.
- [`CoreApplication.Suspending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.suspending.aspx) will be raised when you are being suspended. The system doesn't suspend you immediately when the user switches away (in case they switch back quickly, eg they had accidentally hit the Start button). Instead it waits a few seconds before raising this event.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could please show how to register CoreWindow.Activated and VisibilityChanged? I know that I can use this.Suspending += this.<MySuspending> But I am not sure how to register those two events for windows phone 8.1 in C#